# Python file-reader will not run in IDLE but works fine in terminal?

Tags: python

So I created this lab assignment for class. It seemed fine, except for it doesn't run at all in idle. Idle opens, and then immediately closes. It ran fine in powershell, and the IDE i was using, but would not run at all for my professor.

The program just opens randomNumbers.txt and then lists the values inside. I have had no problems with any of my programs before this one, and this one seems to be the simplest. Is there a simple mistake I'm overlooking? As well as that, if you have any suggestions as to methods i can use to optimize this code id love the suggestions, I've been using python for 2 months now.

Sorry if this post was a bit long, just really confused.

---

```
import time, sys

def main():

     global file

     file = open("randomNumber.txt","r")

     prepArray()

     print("\n-----------\n# | Value\n-----------")

     printArray()
     file.close()

     closeInput = input("\nPress ENTER to exit")
     print("Closing...")

def prepArray():

     global numberSplit
     global file

     openFile = input("Open randomNumber.txt (Y/N): ")
     print("\n")

     if openFile.lower() == "y":

         try:
             f = open("randomNumber.txt","r")
         except IOError:
             print("Error opening file: Did you run the generator first?")
             main()

     elif openFile.lower() == "n":
         sys.exit()

     else:
         print("\nInvalid input, enter either (Y for yes, N for no)\n")
         main()     

     numberSplit = file.readline()
     numberSplit = numberSplit.split(",")
     numberSplit = numberSplit[:-1]  

def printArray():

     global numberSplit

     lineCount = 1
     totalCount = 0

     for item in numberSplit:
         print(lineCount,"-",item)
         lineCount += 1
         totalCount += float(item)

     print("\nTotal:",round((totalCount),2))
      main()
```

randomNumbers.txt just contains

> 119.18,470.54,159.89,360.56,47.15,489.77,242.54,

Comment: probably current directory is different from IDLE.

Comment: To follow up with @Jean-FrançoisFabre's response, perhaps opt to use absolute path instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing your code and its work fine! I'm sure your problem is you haven't randomNumbers.txt in the same folder, please try to put your txt file in the same folder where is your script and it'll work! ;-)

Comment: The txt file, text file generator, and text file reader are all in the same folder. Thats the confusing thing. It SHOULD work.

Comment: I can't see your folder directory but I'm seeing you call your file randomNumbers.txt when your code said randomNumber.txt (note without 's') could be the problem if its the same in your directory.

Comment: @MilesNocte In IDLE, do: `import os`, `print(os.getcwd())`.  If you are launching IDLE from a GUI, it is probably looking in a different path than the rest of your files.